# Gatsby client side routing with Netlify redirect

Tags: gatsby, server-side-rendering, netlify

I have a Gatsby project and I'm trying to achieve the following.

1. When the user navigates to `/movies`, it would show a list of movies
2. When the user click an item from the list, it would navigate to `/movies/:movieId` to display detailed info of that movie.

Here is the problem I'm experiencing on Netlify

1. If a user visits an `/movies/:movieId` directly, or do a hard reload. Then a flash of 404 would appear before the page actually load.

Here is my attempted solution:

1. Install the `gatsby-plugin-netlify` to handle the `_redirects`
2. However, now instead of the flash of 404, it is the flash of the `/movies` page instead.

This is what I want to achieve

1. Each `/movies/:movieId` page has a loading state, so I would like to show that when the user visits the route directly.

The only solution I can think of is to create another route `/loading`, and setup the following redirect rule in netlify

```
/movies/*  /loading 200
```

But I don't want users to be able to visit the `/loading` page either. Is there a way for me to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to debug the problem because it's not common that the flash of 404 page appears when entering to an existing page.

Regarding the attempted solution: `gatsby-plugin-netlify` handle redirects by creating a custom `_redirects` file, however, if you want to add your own or override them, you will need to create a `_redirects` file in your root directory and deploy it. Just add:

```
/movies/*   /movies
```

Note that the default status for the redirect is a `301`. The `200` of your code is a success that makes no sense there. You can omit it. You can check for further information about the [`_redirects` file in Netlify's documentation](https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/#syntax-for-the-redirects-file).

A cleaner solution is to set a React state that handles a loading component. By default, it would be set to `true` (and visible) and once the page is loaded you can `false` it. In that way, are not creating a useless route/page and you are handling a loading on the same page (improving the SEO). There you can play with it by redirecting manually the user in X seconds if the loading state is set to true

Comment: Thanks for the response. The `/movies` page and the `/movies/:movieId` page have different layout. Is there a way to show the loading state of the single movie page instead when the user visits that url directly?

I won't be able to use the `createPage` action because I don't know the `path`.

Comment: The idea of using `createPage` method is precisely to create dynamic paths for any content without taking care of the paths. You can set a loading component and, depending on the previous page, remove it or keep it (and redirect if you want). `<Link>`and `location` allows you to do it.